# Qual é a diferença entre array_replace e array_merge?

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre  `array_replace` e `array_merge`, pois em alguns casos as duas parecem ter comportamentos similares.

Exemplo:

```
  $informacoes = ['nome' => 'wallace', 'idade' => 36];

  array_replace($informacoes, ['idade' => 26]);
```

Saída:

```
[
    "nome" => "wallace",
   "idade" => 26,
]
```

No caso do `array_merge`, temos o mesmo resultado:

```
array_merge($informacoes, ['idade' => 26]);
```

Saída:

```
[
    "nome" => "wallace",
   "idade" => 26,
]
```

- Qual é a diferença principal entre as duas?
- Quando eu deveria utilizar uma ou outra?

Answer (score 10):

Para arrays associativos, que é o seu exemplo ambos trabalham da mesma forma.

Se você analisar este exemplo comparando array_replace vs array_marge vs operador de união, vera que cada tipo de array tem o seu diferencial:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Arrays númericos:**

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = array(2, 3, 4);

var_dump(array_merge($a, $b));
var_dump(array_replace($a, $b));
var_dump(($a + $b));
```

**O que sabemos deles:**

Merge não substitui os números.

Replace substitui.

Operador de adição  não acrescenta os elementos existentes no ultimo array que não estão no primeiro.

**Arrays Associativos:**

```
$a = array("batman" => "loser", "superman" => "win", "SuicideSquad" => "Awesome");
$b = array("batman" => "win", "superman" => "loser", "movie" => "Good");


var_dump(array_merge($a, $b));
var_dump(array_replace($a, $b));
var_dump(($a + $b));
```

**O que sabemos deles:**

Tanto no replace quanto merge são substituído os valores que batem com as chaves e mantido o que tiver de diferente entre eles.

Na adição  ele ignora as chaves iguais e acrescenta apenas o que tiver de diferente, não há substituição.

No terceiro comparativo se configura as caracteristicas do primeiro caso e do segundo.

Imagem de https://softonsofa.com.